# How to check the old password user entered is correct in MVC Entity Code-First Approach?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, change-password

I have an Edit View of Application Users from where user can change their details. The view contains username, email, old password, and new password. As, user enter old password I want to check in database with ajax whether user entered correct old password or not? If old password is correct so I will enable new password otherwise I need to show message to user that password is incorrect. How can I achieve this? Is there any remote method to do it?

**View Model**

```
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Old password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    public string NewPasswordCompare { get; set; }
```

**Ajax Code**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Verify").click(function () {
            var oldPassword = $('#Password').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetPassword")",
                data: {'id':@Model.Id, 'password': oldPassword},
                datatype: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        console.log("Working");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetPassword(string id, string password)
        {
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
                var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
                if (UserManager.CheckPassword(user, password))
                {
                    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
```

Ajax Request Not Working.

Comment: you must try it first

Comment: I already have tried. Let me share code here.

Comment: [UserManagerExtensions.CheckPassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497468(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: I have modified my code please check.

Comment: @tchelidze how?

Comment: @ArmaanLabib [Google it](https://www.google.ge/search?q=UserManager.CheckPassword+example&oq=UserManager.CheckPassword+example&aqs=chrome..69i57.7965j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
            var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
            if (UserManager.CheckPassword(user, password))
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is arguments. I am passing two arguments but controller not accepting two parameters/

Comment: Updated. I need Id as well. I don't want to get ID by User.Identity I need this

Comment: you must make a model with Id and Password and POST it to a service and get the result, if you want I can write it for you or we can have teamviewer meeting.

Comment: Yea Please when we can have team viewer session?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144080/discussion-between-armaan-labib-and-majid-parvin).

Answer (score 1):

You must hash your received password first, then compare it.

```
var UserManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

String hashedOldPassword = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(password);
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var result = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id && u.PasswordHash == hashedOldPassword).First();
```

it will be worked.

Comment: It is giving red squiggly under <User> ?

Comment: change it to your User-Model, you might have **ApplicationUser** .

Comment: I am trying but my code not working. I have modified my code.

Comment: leave it, I've put another answer for you.